# What are IN and OUT parameter in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

What are `IN` and `OUT` parameter in SQL Server?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

IN Parameters - parameters that pass data TO a stored Procedure

OUT Parameters - parameters that are used to RETURN data FROM a stored procedure

Refer MSDN for more details on procedures with [IN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378675%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) and [OUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378108%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) params and how to use them

Examples of how IN/OUT are used with TSQL can be found here:
[SQL Server Stored Procedure Basics](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25288&seqNum=9)