# Can't access output variable in command text

Tags: t-sql, vbscript, ado

```
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = db
    .CommandText = "SELECT @date = '2019-01-01'"
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@date", adDBDate, adParamOutput))
    .Execute
End With
```

Gives...

> Must declare the scalar variable "@date".

Why can't I access the output parameter in the query text?

Comment: You may be passing `@date` as far as ADODB is concerned but T-SQL still needs it defining. You need to add `DECLARE @date AS DATETIME` to the `CommandText` SQL.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks.

Comment: Although it doesn't assign to the parameter anyway. That appears to be returning a default value.

Comment: Only ever used output parameters via Stored Procedures. You could try declaring the variable as `OUT` to denote it’s an output variable but not sure if that works outside of a stored procedure because technically it’s not a parameter it’s a local variable.

Comment: [Think you’re out of luck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4116925/692942) unless you wrap the SQL in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named parameters work as expected on both sides (Server: SQL Server, Client: ADODB & VBScript for your case) only if the provider supports it. For SQL Server providers it is supported only with commands configured to call a stored procedure with named parameters (where `cmd.CommandType` set `adCmdStoredProc` and `cmd.NamedParameters` set `True`).

For an ordinary command like yours, named parameters are not recognized by the server, only the `?` placeholders recognized as parameters in the query.

So you should try something like the following.

```vb
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = db
    .CommandText = "SELECT ? = '2019-01-01'"
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@dummyForServerNotForClient", adDBDate, adParamOutput))
    .Execute
    ' must print: 2019-01-01
    Response.Write .Parameters("@dummyForServerNotForClient").Value
End With
```

Since the parameter names ignored by servers, you can write the same code by omitting the parameter name, and access the parameter's value by using its ordinal position in the collection. IMHO, with the lack of explicitly named parameters the code becomes more logical and readable.

```vb
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = db
    .CommandText = "SELECT ? = '2019-01-01'"
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter(, adDBDate, adParamOutput))
    .Execute
    ' also must print: 2019-01-01
    Response.Write .Parameters(0).Value
End With
```

I hope this helps you to understand the concept.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from T-SQL because the variable `@date` hasn't been declared.

Adjust the T-SQL string you are passing into the `ADODB.Command` to declare the variable;

```
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = db
    .CommandText = "DECLARE @date AS DATETIME; SELECT @date = '2019-01-01';"
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@date", adDBDate, adParamOutput))
    .Execute
End With
```

A simple way to debug these types of issues is to use the SQL Server Management Studio to run the query raw.

```sql
SELECT @date = '2019-01-01'
```

If you had tried to run the query without the declaration you would have got the same error with a bit more detail.

```
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Must declare the scalar variable "@date".
```